# MPMoviePlayerController - no audio

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am facing a unique problem. I have this app uploaded on app store. I am using MPMoviePlayerController in the app. Many people have complained that they are getting no sounds in the videos.

When I asked them what is the os version - all of them have iOS 5.0. Now I also updated my iPad to iOs 5 and tested the app. I am getting no problem. Everything is working fine.

What can be the problem? How do I resolve this issue because I am unable to recreate this error in my iPad?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I experienced the same problem.
I don't have sound on my Ipad1 with IOS5 but I have the sound on my Ipad 2 with IOS5.
Ask your client what they have

Comment: Same here. No audio on iOS 5.  Did you find a fix?

Comment: No! Let me know if you find a fix...

Comment: Just unmute the audio programatically

Comment: [[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:<insert float here>];